# jQuery: Smooth resize of a table cell for text replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table without fixed width columns (an this is ok so). Long text is at the moment printed out twice: First 50 Letters and the complete text in an hidden field.

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vrtf6q14/

When clicking on the short version, colwidth (and height) decreases, when the text is faded out and then increased to full size. And then vice versa.

Is there any trick, to "smooth" resize the cell to its new size? And is it possible to toggle both texts the same time on top of each other? Using divs and `position:absolute` maybe?

Maybe it's totally simple, but I'm stuck.

Comment: It's a little bit 'smoother' if you animate both span simultaneously : https://jsfiddle.net/9p5m4nja/

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply CSS transitions to TR or TD elements.

You can however wrap the content of the TD elements in DIVs and apply animation/transforms to the div. The TDs should animate scale/width/whatever along with the Div's inside them.

```
<tr>
  <td><div>Your Content</div></td>
  <td><div>Your Content</div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: But the effect is the same: In that moment, when the 2nd div/span get visible, the cell spreads spontaneously. I need something like this:

1. get the size of both the visible and hidden span/div
2. calculate the difference
3. scale the cell (or one wrapping div)
4. change/replace the text somehow

Comment: The cell will ALWAYS equal the width of the widest text in the column plus its cellpadding. Animating the div's from 0 width to the width of the widest element should work. In other words, you have to know the width of your widest cell in each column, and then animate all divs in that column to a width equal to that - for each column.